# Running Specflow scenarios cross browser/devices in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, nunit, specflow

Is that possible?

Right now, I have a couple of Specflow Features that I run using Nunit from Visual Studio.

Using [assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)] I can run multiple features at the same time BUT with the same browser. Is there a way to setup something to run multiple browsers/mobile devices?

I saw some examples but nothing using Nunit and Specflow Features..

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to use SeleniumGrid for multiple browsers in parallel.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought, but most of the examples online are using Nunit and Selenium Grid WITHOUT Specflow scenarios. couldn't find any so far

Comment: Here is an example that uses Selenium Grid and SpecFlow+Runner (no NUnit) https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/SeleniumGridWebTest

Comment: You can use it as starting point